# SQL Server: display child row values as in parent as column

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have following tables:

- Master: ID, Description
- Child 1: ParentID, Barcode
- Child 2: ParentID, Group

`Child 1` and `Child 2` can have multiple values for a `ParentID`.

I would like to display only one parent row with all linked child values.

Example:

```
ID Description Barcode1 Barcode2 Barcode3 Barcode 4 Barcode 5 Group1 Group2 Group3 Group 4 Group 5
```

So the first 5 values of every child table linked to the `parentID`.

According to what I read I can't use PIVOT because I only have a value in both child tables and no identifier.

Is this possible to accomplish in a SQL Server view?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT M.ID, 
       M.DESCRIPTION, 
       ( 
              SELECT BARCODE + ' ' 
              FROM   [Child1] C 
              WHERE  C.PARENTID = M.ID FOR XML PATH('')) AS BARCODE, 
       ( 
              SELECT [GROUP] + ' ' 
              FROM   [Child2] C 
              WHERE  C.PARENTID = M.ID FOR XML PATH('')) AS GROUPS 
FROM   [Master] M
```

Comment: Will try and let you know. Thanks for the fast response